# Postmaster & Escort Add-on

Tags: email, postmaster

Does this replace the need for the Escort add-on? I also use Subscriptions by DevDemon, so I may need both, not sure if the two play nicely together or Postmaster simply replaces the need for the Escort module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Escort](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/escort) will send any and all emails generated by ExpressionEngine (or add-os which use EE's built-in email library) via your selected third-party email service. It's quick an simple.

[Postmaster](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/postmaster) can also do this, but in a more complex manner, if you create a parcel using the [send_system_email](https://objectivehtml.com/postmaster/hooks/send-system-email) hook. Its advantage is that you could also customize those emails via the Postmaster parcel you create (as you have to build a template for those system emails). But Postmaster's main strength really is in creating custom email notifications which fire when certain events happen.

If you use Escort for your system-generated emails, and Postmaster for custom emails, they will play together just fine.